# Fastest Way to Round to the Nearest 5/100ths

Tags: python

I have numbers that I want to go from:

```
1.215145156155 => 1.2
1.368161685161 => 1.35
1.578414616868 => 1.6
```

(*Note: the hundredths place should not be marked if it is zero.)

What's the ***fastest*** way to do this?

This is what I have right now, and it is not fast enough:

```
def rounder(v):
    v = str(round(float(v),2))
    if len(v) == 3: v = v + str(0)
    d0 = int(v[0])#ones
    d1 = int(v[2])#tenths
    d2 = int(v[3])#hundredths
    if d2 <= 4:
        return str(d0)+'.'+str(d1)
    elif 4 < d2 < 7:
        return str(d0)+'.'+str(d1)+str(5)
    elif d2 >= 7:
        if d1 != 9:
            return str(d0)+'.'+str(d1+1)
        if d1 == 9:
            return str(d0+1)+'.'+str(0)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Scale, round, unscale.

```
round(20*v)/20
```

I should warn you that the behaviour might surprise you:

```
>>> round(20*1.368161685161)/20
1.3500000000000001
```

The rounding is working correctly, but IEEE numbers can't represent 1.35 exactly. Python 2.7 is smarter about this and will choose the simplest representation, `1.35`, when printing the number. The actual stored value is identical in 2.7 and earlier versions.

Comment: If you use `str()` on the number, the long decimal should go away. (Or use %f or `.format()` to constrain the length explicitly.)

Comment: Just entering `1.35` in Python 2.6 also gives `1.3500000000000001`.  The updated algorithm in Python 2.7 and Python 3.x gives `1.35`.

Comment: @Brandon, @Sven: Thank you for the qualifying remarks. They really help to round out my answer (sorry, I just couldn't help myself). P.S.: The "Thank you" is genuine.

Answer (score 3):

I would try

```
round(v * 2, 1) / 2
```

Should be pretty fast.  The other suggested variant

```
round(v * 20) / 20
```

seems to be even slightly faster:

```
$ python -mtimeit "round(1.368161685161 * 2, 1) / 2"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.291 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit "round(1.368161685161 * 20) / 20"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.248 usec per loop
```

Comment: To the down-voter: this expression is correct. But the fact that it was down-voted underscores why I dislike it. It is a bit too clever for its own good.

Comment: @Marcelo: I considered my first expression to be even more natural and not clever at all, but I get used to the fact that people don't think the way I do.

Comment: I'm guilty of this too, at times. I've been pulled up for `(a == 2) ^ (b == 3) ^ (c == 4)` because bit-wise operators, "shouldn't be applied to boolean types". Of course, I cop even more flak if I write `(a == 2) != (b == 3) != (c ==4)` (and rightly so in Python, since `False ^ False ^ True` is not the same as `False != False != True`; but I do this in C++ from time to time).

Comment: marcelo, people will go on fighting over this. one faction finds it so cool to write `FLAG_A | FLAG_B` and the other faction is disturbed by lack of semanticity and clarity. likewise using `^` in place of `!=` is not the intended usage of `^`, it just accidentally works (like `a = b or c` accidentally works---for some cases). in javascript, bit-oring numerical flags is actually quite slow, which doesn't keep people from using punch card era idioms in the web browser.